# Is there an advantage to smashing two rocks with one swing?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

When mining for gems, is there an advantage to smashing two rocks with one swing, over taking two swings?

How does it affect the durability of my weapon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The durability used is the same amount as if you hit the ore deposits one at a time. As already answered, the only advantage is the time it takes to hit the deposits.

Comment: Thanks for answering Rmoomy, Can you cite a source?  Or is this something you tested yourself?

Comment: I've tested this myself. Think of it this way. If you swing once and hit both deposits, you are still hitting two separate deposits. Durability is decided on how many things you hit that take away durability, not just if you hit something in a swing.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to test this myself.  How did you go about it?

Comment: Here's what I do. Find the durability of a weapon. It can be whatever you have on you. For instance, a traveler's sword has 20 durability. Before testing, save the game. (not using autosave) You use this save file for if you mess up or if you don't want to permanently use any of your weapon's durability. Then test whatever you want. In this case, find two ore deposits and a weapon. If using the traveler's sword, break the two ore deposits. This will take two hits each, for a total of four durability lost. Then use the remaining 16 durability on whatever you want. (like an enemy)

Comment: If it breaks right after the 16 hits on the enemies, you'll know that you were correct and used four durability on the two deposits, or two each. If it takes less, you know that you were wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious advantage is *time* - one hit takes less time than two. And since every weapon can be found, made or recharged infinitely many times the only reason you'd ever need to worry about such durability loss is if you don't have any replacement weapons of similar strength.

Comment: Does hitting two rocks with one swing have a net difference in durability of your weapon compared to hitting one rock with one swing twice? Your time point is both valid and good, but I think the OP was also after an answer addressing the durability loss from the aforementioned strikes.